# Updating object properties with objects Angular

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, binding

I am new to angular so forgive me if I use the incorrect terminology! I would also prefer any solutions using the latest Angular version if possible :-) I have some fairly complex use cases.

One of these is a customer edit screen. I have already built the list page and customer details forms, this works well. This also posts back some JSON. I have removed this from my example.

Something that a user must set is a customers stages which can be multiple. Therefore i will use checkboxes.

What I do is load the current user into the scope, then modify its values. then save to a web service. However i have some complex properties and figuring out how to bind these is problematic.

i found this example here which i can get to work if i put the options on my controller directly (shown in code)

http://plnkr.co/edit/cqsADe8lKegsBMgWMyB8?p=preview

however I cannot bind the check boxes on the currentUser.pipe properties. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

kind regards

jim

```
//our object definitions are here
function User(Firstname, Lastname, Id) {
this.Firstname = Firstname;
this.Lastname = Lastname;
this.PersonId = Id;
this.uuid = "OG6FSDHG6DF86G89DSHGDF8G6";

//hold the customers source
this.source = 2;

//these are used to populate our selection boxes
this.pipe = new Object();

//PROBLEM CODE IS HERE
//I WOULD LIKE TO OUTPUT A CHECKBOX FOR EACH ITEM AND THEN UPDATE THE SELECTED VALUE WHEN  A USER CLICK IT
this.pipe.stages = [
    { id: 1, text: 'STAGE 1', selected: true },
    { id: 2, text: 'STAGE 2', selected: false },
    { id: 3, text: 'STAGE 3', selected: true },
    { id: 4, text: 'STAGE 4', selected: false }
];

this.getFullName = function () {
    return this.Firstname + " " + this.Lastname + " " + Id;
};

}

function UserController($scope) {


//called to populate the customers list
$scope.populateCustomers = function () {

    //this will be populated form the server. I have extra code which allows     th euser ot select the customer and edit it and this works fine.
    //I have removed the superflous code
    $scope.userList = [
      new User("John", "Doe", 1),
      new User("Henri", "de Bourbon", 2),
      new User("Marguerite", "de Valois", 3),
      new User("Gabrielle", "d'Estrées", 4)
    ];
};

$scope.populateCustomers();

// the currentUser pobject is loaded by the user and modified. This works fine
$scope.currentUser = $scope.userList[0];

//if i add the stages here i can get them to update however these are different for each
//customer and would like the state to be held accordingly
$scope.stages = [
    { id: 1, text: 'STAGE 1', selected: true },
    { id: 2, text: 'STAGE 2', selected: true },
    { id: 3, text: 'STAGE 3', selected: true },
    { id: 4, text: 'STAGE 4', selected: true }
];


}
```

Here are the templates i have used. This one works off scope.stages

```
stages from scope.stages<br />
    <label ng-repeat="stage in stages">
        <input type="checkbox" value="{{stage.name}}" ng-model="stage.selected">{{stage.name}}
    </label>
    <p>stages: {{stages}}</p>
```

And this is what i would like to do however it shows the check boxes but doesnt bind correctly.

```
stages from currentUser.pipe.stages<br />
    <label ng-repeat="stage in currentUser.pipe.stages">
        <input type="checkbox" value="{{stage.name}}" ng-model="stage.selected">{{stage.name}}
    </label>
    <p>stages: {{stages}}</p>
```

Comment: Please provide the template of checkbox.

Comment: @Saad I have added these to my post

Comment: What exactly do you mean its not binding correctly. Is your model not being updated?

Comment: I pasted your code into an HTML file and it's working fine. I would suspect that what is being retrieved for the current user varies in format somehow. Can you post the JSON you get back for an actual customer? I suspect there's a discrepancy there somewhere.

Comment: @MikeFeltman ah Mike, if I could order you a pizza I would! There was an error in the JSON handler. It would seem my code was all good after all. Well at least I had my first post on here! Thanks for taking the time to assist! :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything works perfectly. I think you have print the wrong variable in the  `currentUser.pipe.stages` template. It will be `<p>stages: {{currentUser.pipe.stages}}</p>`.

```
stages from currentUser.pipe.stages<br />
<label ng-repeat="stage in currentUser.pipe.stages">
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{stage.name}}" ng-model="stage.selected">{{stage.name}}
</label>
<!-- Print currentUser.pipe.stages -->
<p>stages: {{currentUser.pipe.stages}}</p>
```

See this [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/hQ6j7k1dnPAozQKmxJUJ?p=preview). Its binding properly.